# IE8 rendering of XML/XSLT fails with error

Tags: xml, xslt, internet-explorer-8, webbrowser-control

I have a webpage that is served as XML/XSL file pair. With IE8 - Version 8.0.7601.17514.  the rendering fails on Windows 2008 R2 SP1.

## The exact error message is as below:

The XML page cannot be displayed

### Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later.

## The stylesheet does not contain a document element. The stylesheet may be empty, or it may not be a well-formed XML documen...

After clicking on Refresh button, the page gets display correctly on browser.

## Here are the samples of XML and XSLT files:

## File: ExternalTest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="https://mymachine/cdcatalog.xsl"?>
    <catalog>
      <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
      </cd>
    </catalog>
```

=================================================================================

## File: cdcatalog.xsl

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
      <body>
      <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
          <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
          </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
```

If I modify ExternalTest.xml file with following line:

```
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://mymachine/cdcatalog.xsl"?>
```

then I can able to view ExternalTest.xml file in IE without any issue.

As per my observation, IE 8 throws an error when we refer xslt file over https for first time when we click on xml file. After refreshing same page, the web page displays correctly.

Does anyone come across such issue and what could be resolution to it?

Comment: How do you expect anyone to answer this question without seeing the XML and XSLT code? Please show those things so that people can try to reproduce the behaviour you describe.

Comment: The error you get tells you that the XSLT file is not well-formed XML, is not XSLT or does not exist at that location. But to help you further and tell you why that is, you should update with a minimal set of XML and XSLT to reproduce your problem. Please take a minute and read [ask], to help us help you.

Comment: Thanks Mathias and Abel! Updated my question with sample XML and XSLT.

Comment: I copypasted your files whth the following changes:
1) `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>` — I put both files to the same folder
2) `Add </xsl:stylesheet>` at the end of cdcatalog.xsl. 
And it works fine for IE 8.0.6001.18702

Answer (score 0):

The given `cdcatalog.xsl` has an error — there is no closing tag

`</xsl:stylesheet>`